# MongoDB shell : print results

Tags: mongodb

If I execute ONLY the 1st part of the following short script in Robo3T, I get the results printed to the screen.
If I execute it with 2nd part, I only get the standard answer "Script executed successfully, but there are no results to show".

**How can I print intermediate results such as those expected for 2nd part ?**

I precise that concession & mission are both similar JSON objects.
I spent hours on this simple question. Please help.

```
   var mission = db.mission.find({"googleCalendarEventId":"QiVJdbL"});
while (mission.hasNext()) {
    var record = mission.next();   
    print(record.googleCalendarEventId + "," + record.concessionIdSet[0])
};

// 2nd part //

var concession = db.cursor.findOne({"_id": ObjectId(mission.concessionIdSet[0])});
while (concession.hasNext()) {
    var record = concession.next();   
    print(record)
};
```

Comment: A friend of mine answered that find() returns a cursor and findOne returns a document which means that I could print the second document without the "while" in the second part... Actually it's not enough : just adding the second part prevents printing results. **I don't understand why!!**

var cursor = db.mission.find({"EventId":"QiVJdbL"})
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var r = cursor.next();   
    print(r.EventId + "," + r.concessionIdSet[0])
};   // alone -> prints result
 var concession = db.cursor.findOne({"_id": ObjectId(mission.concessionIdSet[0])});

Comment: You are setting the value of `mission` to the cursor object returned by `find()` and then iterating all of the results in your first loop via `mission.next()`. Your second loop should presumably be nested inside the first if you want to print out values for every `mission` document that matches the first query. I'm surprised there isn't an error when you try to reference `mission.concessionIdSet[0]` or iterate the `findOne()` (which returns a document rather than a cursor), but perhaps the errors are suppressed by Robo3T. I would suggest getting your script running in the `mongo` shell first.

Comment: For some more examples see: [Iterate a Cursor in the `mongo` Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/) in the MongoDB documentation.

Comment: @Stennie, thanks! Indeed just adding the second part blocks showing results of the 1st and in the full script, I don't get the modifications on the DB I'm looking for. What is the "mongo shell" ? I thought it would be the Robo3T shell...

Comment: The `mongo` shell is included when you download or install MongoDB locally: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo. You can also download only the shell binary if you are using a hosted service like MongoDB Atlas. Robo3T is a third party application that embeds an older version of the `mongo` shell (currently the 3.4 shell as of Robo3T 1.2, which is the newest version as of June 2018). That is 2 major releases behind MongoDB and potentially problematic if you are using any server version other than MongoDB 3.4.

Comment: Thanks ! I downloaded noSQL booster which is better than Robo3T, and will try the Mongo shell. My real issue is what you raised : I don't get access to the second object : how can I nest the call to "concession" whithin the "mission" selected in the first place ? Do I need to use a function ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again @stennie, for others who would have the same issues, here's one code that worked for me and the 2 errors I committed :
1/ difference between find (--> cursor) and findOne (--> 1 element)
2/ actions in the loop had to be nested inside the loop --> I used a function and it works:

```
const missions = db.mission.find({
   $and:[{"concessionToInvoice": {$exists: false}},
   {"concessionIdSet":{$size:1}}]
}); 
  missions.forEach((mission) => {
   const concession = getConcession(mission);
   print(mission.googleCalendarEventId+"- invoice to :"+concession.name);
   mission.concessionToInvoice = getConcessionToInvoice(concession); //another function
   db.mission.save(mission);
});

function getConcession(mission){
       const concession = db.concession.findOne({"_id": ObjectId(mission.concessionIdSet[0])});
       return concession;
}
```